# Há como evitar o bloqueio do WhatsApp?

Tags: php, whatsapp

Recentemente implementei em um site um gatilho para enviar mensagens WhatsApp via PHP, mas em tempos o usuário remetente bloqueia(WhatsApp), há algum método para evitar esse bloqueio? Macete, ou algo?.

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

> {"status":"fail","reason":"blocked"}

Comment: WhatsApp não tem APi pública, então sempre vai dar problema. Usar Telegram não é uma opção?

Comment: **Relacionado:** [Enviar mensagem para WhatsAPP via sistema](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/130096/3635)